# Steps to enable "Information Management Policy"

Tags: list, web-services

Kindly let me know the steps needed to enable the Information Mgmt Policy. 
Is it enabled at the central admin level or at the site collection level.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your list or library settings and click the Information management policy settings  link.

Comment: Okay, i can set the policy settings by going to the list settings. But, when i go to 'List Based Retention Schedule' and click 'set a retention stage' the 'recurrence' section is greyed out. Please let me know how can i activate that.

Comment: It's disabled depending on what you have selected in the Action dropdown.